# How to disable sub domain php sessions?

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I do not want to make my php sessions available to any other in the domain.  What do I need to change in my Php configuration so that I can restrict the php sessions to the server they originated on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**session.cookie_domain (string)**

> **session.cookie_domain** specifies the domain to set in the session cookie. Default is none at all meaning the host name of the server which generated the cookie according to cookies specification. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

details : http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

So, by default is restricted to the server it originated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [session cookie parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to restrict the domain access to a specific sub-directory so that all other sub-directories cannot access the cookie.

Edit to add: you'll have to make sure you access the cookie in the context of that sub-directory otherwise you'll be locking yourself out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly before you enable the session you can use [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and set the domain of the session cookie, this would make the session only persist on the right domain and your other domains wouldn't have session info.  You could also check the $_SERVER varaible for the request and check the domain manually and don't invoke session_start if its not the right domain.